# Reversi 2D array print

Tags: c++, console-application

(this is homework) I'm trying to print a Reversi board with a row and column header. My question is why isn't the periods being printed but the "B" and "W" are being printed. Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;
const int BOARD_SIZE = 8, MOVE_SYMBOL = 3;
void PrintBoard(char board[8][8]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   const int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

   char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE] =
 {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
 };
PrintBoard(board);
}
// Prints current state of Reversi Board 15L
void PrintBoard(char board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]) { 
char output[MOVE_SYMBOL] = { 'W', ' . ', 'B' };
cout << "\n- 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7";
for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
  cout << "\n" << i;
  for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
     cout << output[board[i][j] + 1];
   }
}
```

Output:

```
- 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0
1
2
3   BW
4   WB
5
6
7        Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: +1 for being refreshingly honest about your homework :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the witespace that surouds your period.  A char sohold be ONE single position so `'.'` and not `' . '`.

Comment: Gahh, I'm bad. Thanks for catching my failure. I'll accept this answer asap.